# Change a simple html form to be mobile compatible

Tags: html, forms, responsive-design

I have a VERY simply html form (an image with some text & select fields) which I would like to change to be available also for mobile devices.

What's the SIMPLEST solution for accomplishing this task ?

I found many explanations on the web, but they are all much too complex for my needs... Basically I just want to have the width of the form adjustable according to device, nothing more :)

Any reference to a SIMPLE tutorial that explains how to do the most basic adjustments for mobile ?

Comment: What have you found / tried yourself?

Comment: many... I found the following php project http://code.google.com/p/phpmobilizer/ which requires sub-domain, looks like a overhead for me. Found the following tutorial http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design which is too detailed for me... I checked some services that appear in this blog http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/convert-websites-for-mobile-devices but didn't get any results.. As I said, I hoped to find a VERY simple example the demonstrates how to build the simplest html page possible and to continue from there..

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to build a Responsive Layout.

For instance:

```
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .yourFormClass {
            /* Some rules */
        }
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
        .yourFormClass {
            /* Some rules */
        }
  }

  /* other resolutions... */
```

I suggest you to read these articles:

1. [How To Use CSS3 Media Queries To Create a Mobile Version of Your
   Website](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/);
2. [CSS media queries by Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).